# .htaccess write commands if hostname equals to

Tags: php, .htaccess

It is possible write any kind of condition (IF) in .htaccess to apply some specific actions ?

```
#if hostname = xxx then
php_flag  display_errors                  on
php_flag  display_startup_errors          on
#end if
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use [Apache Expressions on Apache 2.4+](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html).

For example:

```
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} == 'xxx'">
php_flag  display_errors                  on
php_flag  display_startup_errors          on
</If>
```

> **UPDATE:** is possible use like/contains in operator? Something like HTTP_HOST like `*.test.mydomain.com` ?

You can use various operators. For that example, you probably want to use a regular expression (using the `=~` operator). For example:

```
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} =~ m#\.test\.mydomain\.com$#">
:
</If>
```

Comment: I think...it is possible use like/contains in operator ? Something like HTTP_HOST like '*.test.mydomain.com' ?

Comment: There are various operators that can be used in an Apache Expression. If you want a "like" or "contains" type comparison then you are probably after a regular expression (regex). I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks @MrWhite, I did some tests on my development environment and it works fine , but my problem now is other. On Apache 2.4 the syntax like XXX =~ /expression/ work, but my production still Apache 2.2, and when I use it the server simply crash, probably not supported on 2.2

Comment: Yes, Apache Expressions (as discussed above) are a new feature of Apache 2.4, they are not available on Apache 2.2. If you are still on Apache 2.2 then you can't do this in `.htaccess` alone... you will need access to the server config to proceed further (in order to `Define` a variable that can be checked later in `.htaccess`). However, depending on how your vHosts are configured, this may not be practical. It may be preferable to define these "PHP settings" in your PHP code itself.

Comment: Thanks again @MrWhite, the problem in 2.2 is if I leave the PHP _resolve the problem_ and show exceptions, unfortunatelly I receive only a 500 internal server error on screen and none event is recorded on log. In 2.4 I can force the server to show the error on screen/intercept using custom error handler code that I wrote but in 2.2 I'm totally blind. Well....again, thanks for your time to reply and clarify the points

Comment: Are you trying to trap/display _parse_ errors? PHP will trigger a 500 response if it encounters a fatal error (eg. E_PARSE or uncaught exception) and display_errors is off. However, you should still be able to examine the server's error log for details of this error?

Comment: Yes, this is the scenario. For example, my dev enviroment run under Apache 2.4 + Php7 and on production on Apache 2.2 + PHP5, so some features (and believe the code is **really old**) fire some errors but all is a 500 error (and none log to check). This configuration under htaccess is very usefull because put the directives before the PHP parser cause a error and apache simply give me a 500 error and no log