# Exactly wording of <If "HTTP_HOST == domain "> expression

Tags: apache-2.4, .htaccess

I found this [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/1003392/htaccess-write-commands-if-hostname-equals-to) but unfortunately the placeholder `xxx` isn't clear to me.

---

**Update after a comment:**

I owe the domain `www.this-is-my-domain.com` and this domain is receiving requests from `https://my.some-domain.com`. When `this-is-my-domain.com` - which I fully control - receives a request from `my.some-domain.com` then I want to do something in `.htacces` [**NO REWRITE!**] and therefore I need this `<If>` expression.

---

I need to know in `.htaccess` when the request is coming from a certain domain, like `https://my.some-domain.com`.

If have tried

```
<If "%{REMOTE_HOST} == 'my.some-domain.com/' ">
<If "%{REMOTE_HOST} == 'my.some-domain.com' ">
<If "%{REMOTE_HOST} == 'https://my.some-domain.com' ">
<If "%{REMOTE_HOST} == 'https://my.some-domain.com/' ">
<If "%{REMOTE_HOST} =~ /my.some-domain.com/ ">
<If "%{REMOTE_HOST} =~ m/my\.some-domain\.com$/ ">
```

And other dozens combinations but no one *triggers*. I am still not capable to figure out how to write it. Studying https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/de/expr.html didn't really help.

**My question:**

How do I have to write this `<If>` expression so it triggers when the request is coming from `some-domain.com`.

Comment: What do you mean by "the request is coming from"?

Comment: It's still not clear what you mean by the above phrase, "the request is coming from"? How are you determining that the request is coming _from_ that domain? The `REMOTE_HOST` server variable contains the resolved hostname of the client making the request. Most of the time this is simply the IP address. And depending on how the server is configured, this might _always_ be the IP address. Or, do you mean the "referring website? eg. `my.some-domain.com` is linking to your site and a user is following this link? Both these scenarios could be described as "coming from", but they are very different.

Comment: @MrWhite Yes, thank you, I mean "referring website" but it isn't coming from a link which a user clicks, it's a URL called from/within a javascript file and `this-is-my-domain.com` returns to the calling javascript - running at `some-domain.com` - data.

Comment: Sounds like you need [Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin).

Comment: @MichaelHampton Bingo! I solved it now with checking the IP address and it works perfectly, but I would like to use the more human domain names!

Comment: Hhhmm, if you solved it by checking the IP address then that's not the "referrer"? That sounds like the client's IP address? How did you determine the IP address? (Incidentally, your 2nd example above is the correct "syntax" if REMOTE_HOST is to be used. But, as noted, this is often the same as REMOTE_ADDR - ie. the IP address of the client/user accessing your site.)

Comment: you want to use HTTP_HOST

Comment: @ezra-s Why HTTP_HOST? HTTP_HOST is the "domain" the request is going **to**, not the domain the request is coming **from** - which is what's being asked in the question.

Comment: Yikes, so you really want to check the client ip and make httpd inverse-resolve it.